# reload textures from a file

Tags: 3d, three.js

I am working on a "live image editor" to apply textures in three js.

My application have two parts, a 2D canvas editor and a 3D model that shows the compositions done in 2D part.

You do a image collage in 2d part, saves this composition in a image file and then it is charged in 3d model.

My problem is I can´t reload the image file when user does changes. Yo can do the first composition and charge this in the 3d model correctly, but if you do another change in the composition, save this again, and try to apply to the 3d model, does not reload the data from file, and shows old image. If you load another image file it works correctly, but with the same image file name (the data changes, but the name is the same) does not show the real data.

My code:

```
var cubeCamera, projector;
var texturas=[false,false,false];
var FAR = 1000;
var light, controls;
var SCREEN_WIDTH = _ANCHO3D = 380   ;
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = _ALTO3D = 340;
var container;
var camera, scene, projector, renderer;
var loader;
var composer;
var testParams, testPass;   
var tex, tex2, tex3;
var auxi=1;

$("#visor3D").append("<div id='conten3D' style='width:"+_ANCHO3D+"px; height:"+_ALTO3D+"px; border: 1px solid green;'></div>");

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
init();
animate();

function init() 
        {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 900 );
    camera.position.set( -270, 45, 1 );

    // SCENE
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // LIGHTS                           
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff,1.5);
        scene.add(ambientLight);                

    hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 1.5 );
    scene.add(hemiLight);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer : true } );

    renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );

    container=$("#conten3D");
    container.append(renderer.domElement);

    renderer.gammaInput = true;
    renderer.gammaOutput = true;

    // CONTROLS
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls_set(); 

    loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener('load', function ( event ) 
        {
        object = event.content;                 
        object.position.y = 44;                 
        object.scale.x =0.15;
        object.scale.y =0.15;
        object.scale.z =0.15;
        tex=new THREE.Texture();
        tex2=new THREE.Texture();
        tex3=new THREE.Texture();
                         object.children[11].material.map=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "obj/maps/blanco.jpg");
                object.children[10].material.map=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "obj/maps/blanco.jpg");
                object.children[6].material.map=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "obj/maps/blanco.jpg");
                object.children[8].material.map=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "obj/maps/blanco.jpg");       
                object.children[15].material.map=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "obj/maps/blanco.jpg");
                //aplicartexturas();
                scene.add( object );
                });

            loader.load( 'obj/demo.obj', 'obj/demo0.mtl' );

            }

        function animate() 
            {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
            rotar();
            }

        function render() 
            {
            tex.needsUpdate = true;
            tex2.needsUpdate = true;
            tex3.needsUpdate = true;
            var delta = clock.getDelta();
            controls.update( delta );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }

function aplicartexturas()
{
tex=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "disenos/"+userid+"_LD.png" );
tex2=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("disenos/"+userid+"_LI.png");
tex3=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "disenos/"+userid+"_BA.png" );
object.children[11].material.map=tex;
object.children[10].material.map=tex2;
object.children[6].material.map=tex3;
object.children[8].material.map=tex3;               
object.children[15].material.map=tex3;
}
```

When charge object, I apply a white texture to all
Later, whed I do changes in 2d editor, I aplly these changes with function "aplicartexturas()". In this function, "userid" is a global variable in the page, for difference multiple users access.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this: (1) Remove `needsUpdate = true` from the render loop -- `loadTexture` sets that flag for you. (2) Loading is asynchronous. Assign the new loaded texture after it loads -- in the `loadTexture` callback. (3) The white texture can be shared. There is no need to load it multiple times.

Comment: Was that the problem? If so, I will post an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I remove `needsUpdate=true` (1) and now I use a variable to load the white texture and assign this single variable to all maps (2). But this is strange, I assigned the new loaded texture in callback `tex2=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("disenos/"+userid+"_LI.png", null, function(){
  object.children[10].material.map=tex2;
  });` and nothing changes; also try assign directly the new loaded texture to the map `object.children[10].material.map=new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("disenos/"+userid+"_LI.png");` and nothing happends, BUT if I do BOTH then it works. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, if you want further help, you will have to post a simple, live example to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
        var cubeCamera, projector;
        var texturas=[false,false,false];
        var FAR = 1000;
        var light, controls;
        var SCREEN_WIDTH = _ANCHO3D = 380   ;
        var SCREEN_HEIGHT = _ALTO3D = 340;
        var container;
        var camera, scene, projector, renderer;
        var loader;
        var composer;
        var testParams, testPass;   
        var tex, tex2, tex3;
        var auxi=1;

        $("#visor3D").append("<div id='conten3D' style='width:"+_ANCHO3D+"px; height:"+_ALTO3D+"px; border: 1px solid green;'></div>");
        var clock = new THREE.Clock();
        init();
        animate();

        function init() 
            {
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 900 );
            camera.position.set( -270, 45, 1 );

            // SCENE
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // LIGHTS                           
            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff,1.5);
            scene.add(ambientLight);                

            hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 1.5 );
            scene.add(hemiLight);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer : true } );

            renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );

            container=$("#conten3D");
            container.append(renderer.domElement);

            renderer.gammaInput = true;
            renderer.gammaOutput = true;

            // CONTROLS
            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls_set(); 

            loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener('load', function ( event ) 
                {
                object = event.content;                 
                object.position.y = 44;                 
                object.scale.x =0.15;
                object.scale.y =0.15;
                object.scale.z =0.15;

                tex=new THREE.Texture();
                tex2=new THREE.Texture();
                tex3=new THREE.Texture();

                var blanco=new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "obj/maps/blanco.jpg");
                object.children[11].material.map=blanco;
                object.children[10].material.map=blanco;
                object.children[6].material.map=blanco;
                object.children[8].material.map=blanco;
                object.children[15].material.map=blanco;                    

                scene.add( object );
                });

            loader.load( 'obj/demo.obj', 'obj/demo0.mtl' );

            }

        function animate() 
            {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
            }

        function render() 
            {
            var delta = clock.getDelta();
            controls.update( delta );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }




function aplicartexturas()
{   
tex2=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("disenos/"+userid+"_LI.png", null, function(){
    object.children[10].material.map=tex2;
    });
tex=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("disenos/"+userid+"_LD.png", null, function(){
    object.children[11].material.map=tex;
    });
tex3=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("disenos/"+userid+"_BA.png", null, function(){
    object.children[6].material.map=tex3;
    object.children[8].material.map=tex3;
    object.children[15].material.map=tex3;
    });

object.children[10].material.map=new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("disenos/"+userid+"_LI.png");
object.children[11].material.map=new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "disenos/"+userid+"_LD.png");
object.children[6].material.map=new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "disenos/"+userid+"_BA.png");
object.children[8].material.map=new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "disenos/"+userid+"_BA.png");
object.children[15].material.map=new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "disenos/"+userid+"_BA.png");
render();
}
```

With this code, when I call function `aplicartexturas()` the application reload data from the three different image files and show it "in live", without reload all 3d object.

It´s strange that need two different loads and assignements to work:

```
tex2=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("disenos/"+userid+"_LI.png", null, function(){
    object.children[10].material.map=tex2;
    });

object.children[10].material.map=new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("disenos/"+userid+"_LI.png");
```

and I think this is not very optimal.

If you know a better or optimal way to do it properly, please post it.

Thans all for the answers.